# Adding two arrays to each other where the first value of the array is added to the first value of the second array 100 times?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I cannot wrap my head around the problem I'm trying to solve. I want to make an array to collect all the days (in numbers) that are the beginning of the month (called `starting_days_of_month` for 100 years. To do this I have two arrays as follows for normal years and leap years:

```
beginnings= [0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334] # jan = 31, feb =jan + 28, mar = jan + feb + 31, etc.
leap_beginnings = beginnings.collect { |i| i > 32 ? i += 1 : i }
```

here, beginnings are the beginnings of the month, and leap_beginnings are the beginnings of the month during a leap year (i.e., for `leap_beginnings` after the second month 1 day is added to each month of `beginnings`).

Now I have the years from the beginning of 1900 till the end of 2000. What I want to do is adding the values of the beginnings area from first to last to the `starting_days_of_month` array, but when the year is divisible by 4 (leap year), I want to add the values of `leap_beginnings` to the array.

How do I add two arrays to each other where the first value of the array is added to the first value of the second array and a new array is the output (`starting_days_of_month`) which I can then use as the first value again? (Repeat for 100 years so the output is an array of numbers that contains all the starting days of the month in a 100 year period.)

Comment: You can do this: `leap_beginnings = beginnings.map.with_index {|n,i| (i > 1) ? n+1 : n }`.  I don't think 1900 is a leap year, but 2000 is.  You need to check that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland true, in the original (Project Euler) question 1900 is excluded. Thanks for your help. It is prettier this way. The adding arrays part must be possible to based on a if-statement. Hmm I try to figure out what exactly it is I want to do in an example.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are the two arrays, `a.zip(b).map { |m,n| m+n }` should do it.

Comment: Okay: I try to do this: imagine a year with four months where the starting numbers are, [0,31,60,89] then when I have two years and I add these two arrays as follows `[0,31,60,89] + [0,31,60,89]` I want to have `[0,31,60,89,120 (oops, here the 31 is needed of December),151,170,199]`. And this needs to be different values in leap_year. But now I see I still need to have this 31 value in between.

Comment: The `a.zip(b).map { |m,n| m+n }` works, I only need to take into account now that the first value of the new array should have 31 added to it instead of 0.

Comment: You could always have `a[0] += 31`, but I'll look at this more carefully.  Have you read @spickermann's answer yet? He generally offers good advice.

Comment: I've seen it yes. The output is as expected (last twelve values):
`33425
33425
33456
33485
33516
33546
33577
33607
33638
33669
33699
33730
33760`Every twelfth and thirteenth value are double, while 31 should be added in between.

Comment: @user2609980: I updated my answer to address that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
beginnings = [0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334] # jan = 31, feb =jan + 28, mar = jan + feb + 31, etc.
leap_beginnings = beginnings.map.with_index {|n,i| (i > 1) ? n+1 : n }

def leap_year?(n)
  n % 4 == 0 && (n % 400 == 0 || n % 100 != 0)
end

def offset(array)
  if array.size == 0
    0
  else
    array.max + 31    # because december
  end
end

starting_days_of_month = []

(1900..2000).each_with_index do |year, index|
  days = leap_year?(year) ? leap_beginnings : beginnings

  starting_days_of_month += days.map { |day| day + offset(starting_days_of_month) }
end

puts starting_days_of_month
```

Comment: In do not understand this offset part where you do the max value and an or operator with a 0 behind it. Could you elaborate a bit on this? (Still learning the basics of the language! ;-) )

Comment: If memory serves, `def leap_year(n) n % 4 == 0 && (n % 400 == 0 || n % 100 != 0) end`.

Comment: @Cary you are correct. See the [source](http://projecteuler.net/problem=19) of the problem. Anyhow, I don't understand the offset part... Quite vital. The other issue is that every time a 0 is added it should not be a 0, but it should be a 31 (december). Thanks a lot your answer helps a lot!

Comment: No you are correct about the leap year ;-). The offset part I understand now in the updated code. "I" answered correctly! :)

Comment: @user2609980 : The idea behind the offset is that the number of a day of a month in a following year is the same like the number of the day in this year plus the number of days in the year before. Since the array does not contain the days of last december (only the beginning of december) 31 must be added. And the array might by empty than continue with 0.

Comment: @spickermann Thanks *a lot!*, the code works now and produces the right answer (see [here](https://github.com/erooijak/projecteuler/blob/master/19.rb)). Since I got a lot of help from SO doing it I do not understand everything yet. The part `number_of_days = (0..100).reduce(0) { |tot,i| tot + ((i%4 == 0) ? 366 : 365) }` is unclear since I do not understand what `reduce(0)` means (the 0) and what the arguments `|tot,i|` are in the lambda expression. Furthermore, I think the for-loop below it can be made more "ruby like". I would appreciate your suggestions if you have the time! :)

Comment: For `reduce` read: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce `0` is the initial value for `tot`, `i` is the current element in array. In each loop `366` or `365` is added to `tot`. I would change the loop to `(365..number_of_days).each { |i| sundays.push(i) if i % 7 == 0 }`. But a comment is a bad place to discus code. Asks a new question or open a pull request on github.